# iOS - segue and tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am new to iOS programming. I am following a book and some tutorials to learn it. I need some help in understanding these methods

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PushAppDetails"])
    {
        AppDetailsViewController *appDetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        appDetailsViewController.appDetails =
        [[AppDetails alloc] initWithName:cell.textLabel.text
                             description:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
    }
}



{
    //Set the CellIdentifier that you set in the storyboard
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AppCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Awesome App";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Long description of the awesome app...";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Even More Awesome App";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Long description of the even more awesome app...";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"The Most Awesome App Ever";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text =
            @"Long description of the most awesome app ever seen...";
            break;

        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Unkown";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Unknown";
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

What I am not understanding here is these lines

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
            appDetailsViewController.appDetails =
            [[AppDetails alloc] initWithName:cell.textLabel.text
                                 description:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
```

I got this that I am identifying the segue from this line`[segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PushAppDetails"]` and then I created the object of **AppdetailsViewController** class but i didn't get what this line is doing

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
```

and how this line is calling the bottom table function where the switch function is and description of each cell  and neither this line

```
appDetailsViewController.appDetails =
        [[AppDetails alloc] initWithName:cell.textLabel.text
                             description:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
```

i have a method in my appDetails Class .. why not simply i can do this if i have to access that method

```
 AppDetails *app = new [AppDetails alloc]init
  [app initWithName:cell.textLabel.text
                             description:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
```

I actually come from java so i feel a little difficult to understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewCell *cell = sender;` basically casts `sender` via a variable to an instance of `UITableViewCell`. This is used so you can access `cell.textLabel` and `cell.detailTextLabel` later. Since `sender` is of type `id` you can't write `sender.textLabel`. But you could cast in place if you like:

```
appDetailsViewController.appDetails =
    [[AppDetails alloc] initWithName:((UITableViewCell *)sender).textLabel.text
                         description:((UITableViewCell *)sender).detailTextLabel.text];
```

If you like that more feel free to use it. I personally prefer the assignment to the specific class, because it's more obvious.

and this line does not call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it takes the NSStrings that are already set on the UITableViewCell. Apples code that calls `prepareForSegue:sender:` will pass the touched cell as parameter `sender`.

---

```
AppDetails *app = new [AppDetails alloc]init
[app initWithName:cell.textLabel.text description:cell.detailTextLabel.text];
```

First of all that's not valid Objective-C. If you write code in Objective-C you should not expect that you can use Java syntax.

And in Objective-c you should not call init more than once, depending on the implementation of init this can have many weird effects.

For example take this code:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:self.label];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    if (self = [self init]) {   // calls init
        self.label.text = name;
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you call `init` it will add a new UILabel, and if you call `initWithName:` later, it will add another UILabel, because `initWithName:` will call `init` itself.
So if you call `init` first and then `initWithName:` you end up with two UILabels.
Since you don't know the implementation details of most init methods you are calling you should never call init more than once in Objective-C.

`init...` should always be a part of `[[Object alloc] init...`.